# Total length in IPv4 header

Tags: networking, ipv4

I am trying to learn about IPV4 headers and used Wireshark to take a look at some packets.

[image]

The total length (header length + data length) is 76 bytes. The header length is 20 bytes and the data length is 24 bytes. Were is the other 32 bytes in the total length field coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing the TCP header. The data payload is indeed 24 bytes, IPv4 header is 20 bytes, TCP header must be (76 - 24 - 20) = 32 b.

Comment: That seems to be it. Thanks.